# Get Dates Every Year Between 2 Dates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a report I need to dish out that requires me to get values for the year of account.

The problem I have is I have a start date and an end date. So my theory would be to generate dates that work on the presumption that there's always a year between each.

```
Start: 2016-09-02
Finish: 2019-09-02
```

I need to return a date for each year between the Start and Finish dates so

```
2016-09-02
2017-09-02
2018-09-02
2019-09-02
```

I have looked at using a recursive query but I'm doing this on a large database and need to return the above for different records that are defined by a Unique ID.

For example

```
UNIQUE ID  | Start Date | End Date   |
--------------------------------------
LYJX01PC01 | 2016-09-02 | 2019-09-02 |
POMS01PC01 | 2015-10-11 | 2017-10-11 |
```

I would need to output to

```
UNIQUE ID  | Start Date | End Date   | Year Of Account |
--------------------------------------------------------
LYJX01PC01 | 2016-09-02 | 2019-09-02 |    2016-09-02   |  
LYJX01PC01 | 2016-09-02 | 2019-09-02 |    2017-09-02   |
LYJX01PC01 | 2016-09-02 | 2019-09-02 |    2018-09-02   |
LYJX01PC01 | 2016-09-02 | 2019-09-02 |    2019-09-02   |
POMS01PC01 | 2015-10-11 | 2017-10-11 |    2015-10-11   |
POMS01PC01 | 2015-10-11 | 2017-10-11 |    2016-10-11   |
POMS01PC01 | 2015-10-11 | 2017-10-11 |    2017-10-11   |
```

I can then use 'Year Of Account' on my join.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Apologies - thought I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use a recursive CTE.  This looks like:

```
with cte as (
      select t.unique_id, start_date, end_date, start_date as year_of_account
      from t
      union all
      select t.unique_id, start_date, end_date, dateadd(year, 1, year_of_account)
      from cte
      where year_of_account < end_date
     )
select *
from cte
order by unique_id, year_of_account;
```

Note:  If you can have 100 or more years for a unique id, you'll need to add:

```
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

to the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option is an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,[Year of Account] = B.D 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(YEAR,[Start Date],[End Date])+1) 
                       D=DateAdd(YEAR,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[Start Date]) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
UNIQUE ID   Start Date  End Date    Year of Account
LYJX01PC01  2016-09-02  2019-09-02  2016-09-02
LYJX01PC01  2016-09-02  2019-09-02  2017-09-02
LYJX01PC01  2016-09-02  2019-09-02  2018-09-02
LYJX01PC01  2016-09-02  2019-09-02  2019-09-02
POMS01PC01  2015-10-11  2017-10-11  2015-10-11
POMS01PC01  2015-10-11  2017-10-11  2016-10-11
POMS01PC01  2015-10-11  2017-10-11  2017-10-11
```